# WIM file format details: XML TOTALBYTES

Tags: windows

I am working on some code to process/generate files in Windows Imaging File Format (WIM).

The XML includes a TOTALBYTES tag in the main WIM tag, in addition to a TOTALBYTES tag contained in each IMAGE tag. As far as I can tell, the TOTALBYTES tag in IMAGE represents the total number of bytes (original/uncompressed sizes) of all files contained in the image. The TOTALBYTES element of the main WIM tag holds a different value I can't reconcile to anything. What does that TOTALBYTES value represent?

Answer (score 0):

The TOTALBYTES tag just inside the root WIM tag represents the total file size preceding the XML data; or in other words, the offset in the file at which the XML data is located.